# use protected ctor from virtual base class in derived class

Tags: c++, virtual, derived

I have an abstract pseudo base class for some audio formats with 2 ctors - one works for the derived class  but the other one gives me an error which i can´t solve.
It says that i can´t access the protected member declared in MP3, but why can it reach one ctor but not the other?

```
class Audioformat
{
protected:
    string song="";
    Audioformat(string s) :song(s) {};//This ctor gives me the error
    Audioformat() { song = "unknown";}
public:
    virtual void play()=0;
    virtual void info() = 0;
    virtual ~Audioformat() = 0 {};
};
class MP3 : public Audioformat
{
public:
    using Audioformat::Audioformat;
    void play() { cout << "pseudo-play" << endl; }
    void info() { cout << song << endl; }
    ~MP3() { cout << "MP3" << endl; delete this; }
};
```

Here´s my main :

```
int main()
{

    MP3 song1{};//WORKS
    MP3 song2{ "random trash song" };//ERROR    MP3::MP3(std::string) is inaccessible
    play(song1);
    info(song1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: `delete this;` what?

Comment: `delete this` only works if you make sure that all instances of `MP3` are created with `new` (e.g. by making the constructor private and adding a `static` creator function). And even then, it should never be called *from*  a destructor, because that obviously creates infinite recursion. However, for a class called `MP3`, I cannot imagine a reasonable use case. It would be more typical for event-management systems.

Comment: Oh, and `string song="";` is unnecessary. This isn't Java. Make it `std::string song;`.

Comment: hm my teacher told me that i have to delete this (a pointer to the object) in every destructor to avoid memory leaks(or maybe i got that a bit wrong) - im kinda new to c++ so thanks for pointing that out. i didn´t post it but i wrote using namespace std; in the beginning of the file

Comment: @BMAY - I'm sorry to tell you but your teacher is imparting on you every bad practice in the book.

Comment: @BMAY I think your teacher may have expressed themselves unclearly. Perhaps they meant "delete this object that you created" rather than "write `delete this`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Using declarations alone do not suppresses the implicit declaration of a special class member. In this case the default c'tor ([[namespace.udecl]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#4)):

   > the using-declaration does not by itself suppress the implicit
   >   declaration of the derived class member

   So a public default c'tor for `MP3` is synthesized by the compiler, and invoked in your example.
2. The c'tors introduced by a using declaration basically have the same accessibility they had in the base class ([[namespace.udecl]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#19)):

   > A using-declarator that names a constructor
   >   does not create a synonym; instead, the additional constructors are
   >   accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an
   >   object of the corresponding base class, and the accessibility of the
   >   using-declaration is ignored.

   So the c'tor taking a string is not accessible in `main` since it's protected in `MP3` as well.

If you want to have a public c'tor in `MP3` that accepts a `std::string` you have to define it in full, and forward to the base class c'tor explicitly:

```
public:
  MP3(std::string s) : Audioformat(s) {}
```

Comment: So i have to do something like this MP3(string s):song(s) but song isn´t nonstatic so that doesn´t work.

Comment: @BMAY - I wrote exactly what you have to do. You don't have to guess and get it wrong.

Comment: oh sorry - my website didn´t reload properly - thank you very much